# SQLiteOpenHelper in an external application directory for Api 29 (Android Q)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, android-10.0

How can i do the following situation for android Q (Api 29)?

My intention is to keep in a directory that will continue to exist after uninstalling the application.

It has the following class with its constructor:

```
    public class SqlHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //constructor
     SqlHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

    //rest of the class

    }
```

And in my DAO when calling the database:

```
public class Dao {

    private Context context;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Dao(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void openDataBase() {
        String pathDB = FOLDER_NAME_DBASE;
        //getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecated Api 29
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), pathDB);


        String dBasePath = dir.getPath() + "/" + mydatabse.db3;

        SqlHelper varHelp = new SqlHelper(
                context,
                dBasePath,
                null,
                DBASE_VERSION
        );

        db = varHelp.getWritableDatabase();
    }

   //rest of the class

}
```

Using SQLiteOpenHelper is there any way to create database in Public Documents folder for Api 29?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the manifest [Manage scoped external storage access](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped)

Comment: I will try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Putting a live SQLite database on external storage is not wise for any version of Android. There is a greater risk of data corruption, as other apps might attempt to work with that file.

However, if you wish to ignore that advice, you can use `getExternalFilesDir()` on Android 10 as a base directory for your database. This is accessible by the user, albeit in a not-too-friendly location.

Comment: My intention is to keep in a directory that will continue to exist after uninstalling the application.  With getExternalFilesDir () after uninstalling the app present files will be removed

Comment: @MurilloComino just enable backups, then it will at least be restored when reinstalling (this should be disabled for debug builds).

Comment: @MurilloComino: "My intention is to keep in a directory that will continue to exist after uninstalling the application" -- you will need to do that as part of a backup or export option. You no longer have direct filesystem access to locations like what you seek, and SQLite needs direct filesystem access.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I will follow these suggestions.